# Qt Creator Performance Problems

Tags: c++, performance, qt, user-interface

Everyone's raved about how awesome Qt is and I would really love to use it.  However, after downloading it and trying to build a little Hello World app, the performance of the Qt Creator slogged to the point of being unusable.

1. The main problem is when I switch from "Edit" (code-view) to "Design" (form-view), it takes roughly 30-45 seconds for the form to draw every single time I do this.  [Here is a video of this happening.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a4sKgNEbedo)
2. Hitting CTRL-R to run my application takes 30-45 seconds to display my application.

If anyone has had these issues, please post a suggestion!  I would really love to use Qt.

**UPDATE:** After closing Qt Creator, I notice that Hg Workbench (Mercurial) takes between 1-2 minutes to open (where it's regularly instant).

Comment: I tested your exact code on my OSX workstation. Works instantly. Not sure what could be wrong on your windows installation.

Comment: I use Windows 7 64-bit, MacBook Pro 15" early 2012 model.

Comment: If you are using a mac, have you tried the same thing on OSX instead of bootcamp/vm ?

Comment: Have you tried the native version of QT Creator for OSX?

Comment: I have to work in a Windows environment for my project.

Comment: I think the point was more to just narrow down the issue to being specifically windows under a vm or bootcamp situation.

Comment: I see.  I will install the QtCreator on the OS X installation, thank you for the clarification jdi!

Comment: Windows switches to basic colour scheme, an application (Qt Creator) is very slow and after closing it other applications are really slow. This happens to me whenever I use too much memory and start swapping.  You may check this from the Task Manager. Coincidentally today a new version of Qt Creator (2.5.2) has been released to solve a [memory leak bug on Windows](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2012/08/09/qt-creator-2-5-2-released/).

Comment: Claudio, turns out that installing that update fixed my Qt performance!  I can now use this really awesome library!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you to run the application i.e., qtcreator from a command prompt. Since qDebug will be printing out crucial information about the actions going on, you might have a chance to understand what exactly is causing the slowdown.

Just in case., try the new QtCreator2.5.1 which runs well. Even if this doesn't work, probably there should be something wrong with the OS. Check for any programs that are running in the background which can be choking on the processor.

Comment: Performance issues fixed after installing the update, thank you so much!